# retrieve elastic beanstalk historical logs aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have hosted node js application in elastic beanstalk on AWS environment. We want to check the historical console log of node js. So that we are downloading the logs from Elastic beanstalk application, but it's not containing the historical console log. As we AWS environment hosting is new to us can anybody guide me how to retrieve those historical logs from aws?

Answer (score 1):

When you recycle your instances all the content of the instances is deleted. For that reason you need to copy the logs out of your instance. Amazon has cloudwatch logs where you can feed all the logs from all your servers. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html

I find a bit confusing the process to set it up with beanstalk. I wrote a post on how to do it for a php application: http://www.albertsola.pro/store-aws-beanstalk-symfony-and-apache-logs-in-cloudwatch-logs/